# How do crystals protect electronic spin qubits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, quantum-computer, decoherence

[Defects in SiC crystals](https://www.sciencealert.com/scientists-have-found-another-way-to-get-qubits-working-at-room-temperature) demonstrated entanglement between electronic spin qubits at room temperature. But do we need a *crystal* to protect the state?

My understanding is that crystals, being uniform and symmetric, will not produce decohering local electric fields or magnetic moments and thus protect qubits. I.e. any electric field from the atom to the left is cancelled out by that to the right. However, do we *need* crystals to protect quantum states that are stored in condensed matter?

Nuclear spin qubits are stored in liquid (for NMR quantum computing) which would "averages out" any net electric fields the qubit is exposed to, but they [are probably not scalable](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/277/5332/1688).

For protecting an *electronic* spin qubit, would it be possible to arrange atoms around it in such a way that the fields cancel without crystalline symmetry? If that won't work, would a nanocrystal be enough? It seems unlikely that the qubit would care about anything more than a few atoms away apart from charged or ferromagnetic objects that produce a bulk field.